# Creating an api with parameters names different from database column names in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an existing database table by the name positions and I have a locations api built in rails. The positions table has following columns:

```
 deviceid | servertime | latitude | longitude  | altitude | speed  | address
```

and the locations api has the following parameters

```
device_id | created_at | lat | lon  | altitude | gps_speed  | address
```

Now I want to use the positions database table in my locations api and I want to create the following mapping between them:

```
Database Table Name  |   API Paramater Name         
1) Speed             |   gps_speed
2) Latitude          |   lat
3) Longitude         |   lon
4) deviceid          |   device_id
5) servertime        |   created_at
6) altitude          |   altitude
7) address           |   address
```

Can anyone please tell how can I create this mapping so that values from these columns of positions table can be mapped to these parameters of the locations api?

Comment: It mostly depends what's going on between them. If you're rendering JSON and you'd like to map them at that point, it depends what you're using to serialize them. If you just want it to be done on the model level, you can create methods on your model for each API param, but your queries using active record will still need the db names

Comment: I want map it at model level so that all every where else (in controller, views , serializers, etc  ) I can just work with the api parameter names..

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just rename the db columns? But aside from that I'm not sure there's a way

Comment: Yeah, the database tables are being used by one more application, so if I rename the database table the other application will stop working, and I can not change the names in api also because they are being consumed in mobile app and external systems. All I can do is a mapping between the two. Anyways how can I do mapping in rendering JSON ?

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve this by adding custom alias attribute to the model. Add this file to 'initializers' folder with active_record_extension.rb file name.

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

   def alias_attribute_method(new_name, old_name)
       self.alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)
       self.alias_attribute("#{new_name}=", "#{old_name}=")
   end

  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

You can add alias_attribute_method method inside your model. This will handle CRUD operations also. By adding addition methods there is no performance impact and its negligible.

```
alias_attribute_method :gps_speed, :speed
alias_attribute_method :lat, :latitude
```